# add values of dictionary based of matching of keys and list elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary as:

```
[{
 'doc1': {'hyundai': 12,
   'mercedez': 34,
   'bugatti': 2,
   'honda': 19},
 'doc2': {'tennis': 20,
   'wimbledon': 11,
   'nadal': 57}, 
 'doc3':{'world': ,
   'politics': 8,
   'obama': 7,
   'america': 4,
   'summit': 14,
   'budget': 17,
   'germany': 22
}}]
```

and list of words `l= ['trump','mercedez','wimbledon','nadal','hyundai','tennis']`

All I want to match the list elements with keys of dictionary and get the sum of its values with sorted along with highest sum and if none elements get matched then sum will be zero for corresponding key.

Expected as,

`new_dict={'doc2':88,'doc1':46,'doc3'=0}`

Comment: Why is your ``new_list`` even a list if it only contains one dictionary? Why does it have an entry for ``doc3`` when your input does not? Do you expect the list or the contained dictionary to be sorted?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The value for `doc3` is 0 as non of the list elements got matched with keys for `doc3`. So, the sum would be zero for that. Yeah, I want dictionary to be sorted.Hope you got it :)

Comment: I do not understand why would you have a list of one dictionary?

Comment: The final dictionary should consist key as doc and values would be sum of all matched values and finally I want it to be sorted based on highest sum.@

Comment: This doesnt sound bad at all.  I already have the answer written, but i want to see your attempt

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi 3.7

Comment: I was referring to your input list, why it's list of one dictionary, and not list of dictionaries, where every dict is document?

Comment: @Learner I've already posted an answer, could you take a look?

Comment: @Planet In input list I have a nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate using `.items()`,

then iterate the inner dicts the same way.

like this:

```py
d_list = [{'doc1': {'hyundai': 12,
                    'mercedez': 34,
                    'bugatti': 2,
                    'honda': 19},
           'doc2': {'tennis': 20,
                    'wimbledon': 11,
                    'nadal': 57},
           'doc3': {'world': 0,
                    'politics': 8,
                    'obama': 7,
                    'america': 4,
                    'summit': 14,
                    'budget': 17,
                    'germany': 22}}]

l = ['trump', 'mercedez', 'wimbledon', 'nadal', 'hyundai', 'tennis']


result_d = {}
for doc_name, inner_dict in d_list[0].items():
    result_d[doc_name] = sum(v for k,v in inner_dict.items() if k in l)

new_list = [result_d]

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'doc1': 46, 'doc2': 88, 'doc3': 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
In [131]: A = [{'doc1': {'hyundai': 12, 'mercedez': 34, 'bugatti': 2, 'honda': 19},
     ...:       'doc2': {'tennis': 20, 'wimbledon': 11, 'nadal': 57},
     ...:       'doc3': {'world': 0, 'politics': 8, 'obama': 7, 'america': 4, 'summit': 14, 'budget': 17, 'germany': 22}}]

In [132]: B = ['trump', 'mercedez', 'wimbledon', 'nadal', 'hyundai', 'tennis']

In [133]: dict_comprehension = {key: sum([value.get(b, 0) for b in B]) for key, value in A[0].items()}

In [134]: result = dict(sorted(dict_comprehension.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

In [135]: result
Out[135]: {'doc2': 88, 'doc1': 46, 'doc3': 0}
```

I got your expected output using `dict comprehensions`.